# How come the global variable is not referencing its new value in a different function JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a program where on one HTML screen, a player chooses a specific income (low, medium, or high), and the global variable weeklyPay gets changed based on the player's choice.

```
var weeklyPay;

function getMoney(level)
{
    if (level === "Low")
    {
        weeklyPay = 500; 
    }
    else if (level === "Medium")
    {
        weeklyPay = 1500;
    }
    else if (level === "High")
    {
        weeklyPay = 4500;
        studentLoan = true;
    }

    console.log(weeklyPay);
}

function showMoney(params)
{
    let status = document.getElementById("display-button").innerHTML;
    //getMoney();

    if (status === "Show Networth")
    {
        document.getElementById("display-button").innerHTML = "Hide Networth";
        document.getElementById("networth").innerHTML = "Networth: " + weeklyPay;
    }
    else if (status === "Hide Networth")
    {
        document.getElementById("display-button").innerHTML = "Show Networth";
        document.getElementById("networth").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

However, on the webpage when I call showMoney() to display the money, it says weeklyPay is undefined.

Comment: you never call `getMoney`, let alone with a `Low` `Medium` or `High` as an argument

Comment: I called getMoney on a different screen, the function itself works since I tested it in the console.

Comment: right, so you call showMoney after calling getMoney? the code as shown is far from enough to diagnose your issue

Comment: Yes I do call showMoney after getMoney.

Comment: then it should work

Answer (score -1):

If your function has a local variable with same name as global variable and you want to modify the global variable inside function then use 'global' keyword before the variable name at start of function i.e. As you can see modification done to global variable total is now visible outside the function too.

Comment: there is no `global` keyword in javascript

Comment: there is a global object defined. If you want to create global variables then use var keyword.

Comment: like in the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).